# How Spring Batch Restart logic works on hadoop job?

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-boot, spring-batch

Suppose i have 10 records and some of them are corrupted records so how spring will handle restart.

Example suppose record no. 3& 7 are corrupt and they go to different  reducer then how spring will handle the restart 
1.how it will maintain the queue to track where it last failed.
2.what are the different ways we can solve this one

Answer (score 0):

SpringBatch will do exactly what you tell SpringBatch to do.

Restart for SpringBatch means run the same job that failed with the same set of input parameters. However, the new instance (execution) of this job will be created.

The job will run on the **same data set** that the failed instance of the job ran on.
In general, it is not a good idea to modify the input data set for you job - the input data of MapReduce job must be immutable (I assume, you will not modify the same data set you use as an input).

In your case the job is likely to complete with the `BatchStatus.COMPLETED` unless you put a very specific logic in the **last step** of your SpringBatch job.
This last step will validate all records and if any broken records detected artificially will set the status of the job to `BatchStatus.FAILED` like below:

```
jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.FAILED)
```

Now how to restart the job is a good question that I will answer in a few moments.
However, before restrting the question you need to ask is: **if the input data set for your MapReduce job and the code of your MapReduce job have not changed, how restrt is going to help you?**

I think you need to have some kind of data set where you dump all the bad records that the original MapReduce job failed to process. Than how to process these broken records is for you to decide.

Anyway, restarting SpringBatch job is easy, once you know what is the ID of failed `jobExecution`. Below is the code:

```
final Long restartId = jobOperator.restart(failedJobId);
final JobExecution restartExecution = jobExplorer.getJobExecution(restartId);
```

**EDIT**

Read about [ItemReader, ItemWriter and ItemProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html) interfaces
I think that you can achieve tracking by using [CompositeItemProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemProcessor.html).
In Hadoop every record in a file must have a unique ID. So, I think you can store the list of IDs of the bad record in the Job context. Update `JobParameter` that you would have created when the job starts for the first time, call it `badRecordsList`. Now when you restart/resume your job, you will read the value of the `badRecordsList`and will have a reference.

Comment: Agree but, the problem here is suppose i have 10 records and 3 reducer and suppose 3 rd record goes to reducer1 and 7 th record to reducer 3 and reducer 2 process 3 records 4-6 then how and from whr restart logic will work?WIll  it again process the processed records.DO spring somwhere maintains the processed records?